# Replacing Rows in Pandas DataFrame with Other DataFrame Based on Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataFrames

```
df1
    B   C
A       
0   300 6
1   400 7
2   500 8
3   600 9

df2
    B   C
A       
2   433 99
3   555 99
```

This is how I construct them:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [300, 400, 500, 600], 
                   'C': [6, 7, 8, 9]})
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3],
                    'B': [433, 555],
                    'C': [99, 99]})
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)
```

I want to replace all rows from `df1` with the rows from `df2` based on the index, the result should look like this:

```
df_result
    B   C
A       
0   300 6
1   400 7
2   433 99
3   555 99
```

What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `combine_first`:

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
       B     C
A             
0  300.0   6.0
1  400.0   7.0
2  433.0  99.0
3  555.0  99.0
```

Comment: for me this doesn't work:
i get df1 unchanged as result

Comment: You need to re-assign the output of this method to a new dataframe.  Or assign it back to df1.  This is not an inplace method like 'update'. Try `df_out = df2.combine_first(df1)` `print(df_out)`.

Comment: Current pandas documentation says: "Combine two DataFrame objects by filling null values in one DataFrame with non-null values from other DataFrame." So this no longer gives the behaviour in the original question - non-null values are not overwrittern.

Comment: @Juho This appears to still work for this example.  And, I am not sure this documentation is any different in the past.  Can you provide an example where this is not working?

Comment: @ScottBoston My mistake. I got df1 and df2 confused. I just find the logic a bit confusing as in my particular use case df1 is actually the "master" datatable and df2 the changes we want to make into it (replacing individual rows and adding new ones), yet the syntax df2.combine_first(df1) seems to hint at the opposite. But yes, considering all the unchanged rows are null values in df2 and get replaced by df1, it does exactly the trick.

Comment: How about update multiple columns (i.e. match to same index, but update two or more columns)?

Answer (score 21):

This is what [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) is meant for:

```
df1.update(df2)
>>> df1
       B     C
A             
0  300.0   6.0
1  400.0   7.0
2  433.0  99.0
3  555.0  99.0
```

Comment: The only limitation with this is that only left join is implemented, keeping the index and columns of the original object. Which means if df2 has indices not found in df1, those are not added to df1. Depending on the use case that might be a problem, in which case `df1.combine_first(df2)` works better.

Comment: Need to correct my own comment. Combine_first `df1.combine_first(df2)` works better, if it is sufficient to only replace non-null values in df1 with values from df2. For updating non-null values with the union of the two indices another solution is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Notice using `.loc` will not change the type of column

```
df1.loc[df2.index,:]=df2
df1
Out[20]: 
     B   C
A         
0  300   6
1  400   7
2  433  99
3  555  99
```